# How to Cut Incomplete Rows and Paste In Another Workbook with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am cycling through all the Green Tabs in a workbook.  When I come to a row of data where there is no value in Column G, I select that row, cut it, and open another workbook entitled "Unpaid AR." In that workbook, I find the first unused row, and Paste.  Everything functions properly except for the Paste - nothing pastes, and I have tried several different techniques.  Any ideas what could be going wrong?

```
Public Sub CutNPaste()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim ARRange As String
  Dim ARFilePath As String
  Dim ARcell As Range
  Dim CopyRange As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim varRange As String
    
  ARFilePath = "Unpaid AR.xlsx"

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    If ws.Tab.ColorIndex = 10 Then  'If Tab is Green, Then...
      ReportRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count  'Get how many rows in the report
      Let ARRange = "G" & "2" & ":" & "G" & ReportRows 'Range to Inspect for Blanks
      i = 2
            
      For Each ARcell In Range(ARRange)
        Let CopyRange = "A" & i & ":" & "I" & i 'Set the copy range when blank is encountered
        If ARcell.Value = "" Then
          Range(CopyRange).Select
          Selection.Cut
          Workbooks.Open ARFilePath 'Open the Unpaid AR workbook
          Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select 'Find the first open row
          ActiveSheet.Paste 'This is where NOTHING happens
          Workbooks("Unpaid AR.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True 'Save and close destination wkbk
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
        i = i + 1
      Next ARcell
    End If
 Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Side notes: `Let` is deprecated, just drop that. Then [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Finally, the cut and paste steps should be "as close" to each other as possible, don't open a workbook inbetween, as that may clear the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you BigBen.  I removed 'Let' and also used 'Rows(i).Copy to Copy and 'ActiveCell.EntireRow.PasteSpecial' to Paste.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

i change a little bit...

```
Public Sub CutNPaste()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim ARRange As String
  Dim ARFilePath As String
  Dim ARcell As Range
  Dim CopyRange As Range
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim varRange As String
  Dim wkbTarget As Workbook
  Dim ReportRows As Long

  ARFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Unpaid AR.xlsx"

  Set wkbTarget = Workbooks.Open(ARFilePath) 'Open the Unpaid AR workbook

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Tab.ColorIndex = 10 Then

      ReportRows = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  
        
      For i = ReportRows To 2 Step -1
  
        Set CopyRange = ws.Range("A" & i & ":" & "I" & i)
    
        If ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then
      
          CopyRange.Cut Destination:=wkbTarget.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
      
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    
      Next i
    End If
 Next ws

     wkbTarget.Close SaveChanges:=True 'Save and close destination wkbk

End Sub
```

BR
Bernd